# Swift Get data from Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to fetch image data from firebase storage with swift .

Code :

```
 let ref = Storage.storage().reference().child("users").child("uid").child("savedimage");
 let task = ref.getData(maxSize: 1024*1024*12) { (data, error) in
      if let data = data , let image = UIImage(data: data) {
          print("image exists");
          self.imageView.image = image;
      }else {
          print(error);
      }
 }
 task.resume();
```

But most of the time the app crash after a second of getting the image , and take me to this :

[image]

It's not showing any error in console output so i cannot figure out what's the issue but sometimes it's give me a warning before the crash :

> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: use this method - fileprivate lazy var storageRef: StorageReference = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://fir-chat-") // Firebase Storage URL

Comment: @VishalVaghasiya it's not about storage reference , my question is : why the app crashes after i got my data